# Замена элементов списка словарей по ключу на числа из этих элементов

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть словарь вида:

```
rows = [{'customer': 1, 'item': '10 0 apple', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
    {'customer': 2, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 3, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 4, 'item': '4 0 0 cats', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}]
```

Нужно вытащить из его элементов по ключу "item" числа и записать их вместо элементов. Если в элементе содержатся числа через пробелы или иные символы, то их необходимо слить в одно число. Например, из элемента '10 0 apple' должно получиться '100', '4 0 0 cats' - '400' и т.д.

Мой вариант кода вытаскивает числа из элементов, но не объединяет и не заменяет на сам элемент:

```py
    count = 0
    for element in rows: # Определяем количество словарей в списке
        count += 1
    
    for i in range(0, count+1): # Перебираем каждый словарь списка
        numbers = []
        for j in rows[i]['item'].split(' '): # В каждом словаре сплитим элемент с ключом "item"
            try:
                int(j)
                numbers.append(j)
            except:
                pass
        print(numbers)
```

Comment: 'item': '4 0 0 cats' оставить как 'item': '400 ' (в строке?), а если 'item': 'cats' - пустой ('item': '')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rows = [
    {'customer': 1, 'item': '10 0 apple', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
    {'customer': 2, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 3, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 4, 'item': '4 0 0 cats', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}
]
```

Обойтите элементы списка и измените значение ключа `item`:

```
for r in rows:
    r['item'] = ''.join(i for i in r['item'] if i.isdigit())
```

Теперь в `rows`:

```
>>> rows
[
    {'customer': 1, 'item': '100', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'}, 
    {'customer': 2, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'}, 
    {'customer': 3, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'}, 
    {'customer': 4, 'item': '400', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}
]
```

Оставит значение пустой строкой, если не найдет цифр...

Answer (score 3):

```py
def get_int_from_string(string):  # Получение числа из строки
    value = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, string))  # "Забирание" всех цифр из строки и объединение в одну строку
    return int(value)  # Возврат приведённого к типу int


# Исходные данные
rows = [{'customer': 1, 'item': '10 0 apple', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
         {'customer': 2, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
         {'customer': 3, 'item': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
         {'customer': 4, 'item': '4 0 0 cats', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}]

numbers = []  # Куда будет складываться результат
for row in rows:
    # Для каждого элемента из rows получаем нужное число и кладём в результирующий список
    numbers.append(get_int_from_string(row['item']))

for row, value in zip(rows, numbers):
    print(row['item'], value, sep=' | ')  # Вывод для наглядности
```

Если хотите заменять прям в `rows`, то:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    rows[i] = get_int_from_string(row['item'])
```

Comment: Проблема с заменой есть в том плане, что я не понимаю, как ее делать.

Comment: @AndrewTim Обновил.

Comment: print(rows) дает список чисел [100, 25, 25, 400], а нужен обновленный список словарей.

Comment: Ожидаемый вывод:
rows = [{'customer': 1, 'item': '100, 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
         {'customer': 2, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
         {'customer': 3, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
         {'customer': 4, 'item': '400', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}]

Comment: @AndrewTim *>Нужно вытащить из его элементов по ключу "item" числа и записать их вместо элементов* - какой вопрос, такой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

решение с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

df["item"] = df["item"].str.replace(r"\D", "")
```

результат:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
   customer item     item2 age
0         1  100    3 milk  24
1         2   25  2 orange  23
2         3   25  2 orange  23
3         4  400  76 mango  25
```

если нужен словарь:

```
In [48]: res = df.to_dict("records")

In [49]: res
Out[49]:
[{'customer': 1, 'item': '100', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
 {'customer': 2, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
 {'customer': 3, 'item': '25', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
 {'customer': 4, 'item': '400', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

rows = [{'customer': 1, 'item1': '10 9 apple', 'item2': '3 milk', 'age': '24'},
    {'customer': 2, 'item1': '25 water', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 3, 'item1': '25 water 8', 'item2': '2 orange', 'age': '23'},
    {'customer': 4, 'item1': '4 0 0 cats', 'item2': '76 mango', 'age': '25'}]

for row in rows:
    item = row['item1']  # Получаем нужную строку
    value = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', item))  # Достаём из неё все цифры и объединяем через пустую строку
    value = int(value)  # Приводим к типу int
    #print(value)  # Вывод для наглядности
    del row['item1']
    row['item1'] = value

print(rows)
```

Comment: удалять `row['item1']` необязательно